# StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location. Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404 android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

```
fun saveImageFile(filename: String, mimetype: String, bitmap: Bitmap): Uri? {
    var values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, mimetype)

    val uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
    Log.d("saveImageFileFun", uri.toString())

    try {
        if (uri != null) {
            var descripter = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w")
            if (descripter != null) {
                val fos = FileOutputStream(descripter.fileDescriptor)
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos)
                fos.close()
                return uri
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Camera", "${e.localizedMessage}")
    }
    return null
}

private fun uploadImage(imageFile : File?) {
    if(imageFile != null) {
        val storageRef = Firebase.storage.reference
        val imageRef = storageRef.child("images/${imageFile.name}")
        val uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(Uri.fromFile(imageFile))

        uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful) {
                imageRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                    downloadUrl = uri.toString()
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "이미지 업로드에 실패하였습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

fun uriToFile(uri: Uri?): File? {
    val filePathColumn = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
    var cursor: Cursor? = null

    if(uri != null) {
        cursor = this.contentResolver.query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null)
    }
    cursor?.moveToFirst()
    val columnIndex = cursor?.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])
    val filePath = cursor?.getString(columnIndex ?: 0)

    cursor?.close()

    return filePath?.let { File(it) }
}
```

After taking a photo,
I plan to upload the photo directly to Firebase and store the uri as data.
I am in the process of receiving the URI of the photo I took,
converting it to file format,
then converting the converted file into URI and putting it in putfile().
But when you proceed like this, you will get a result like this.
" StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location.  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404"

```
val uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(Uri.fromFile(imageFile))
```

The problem seems to occur in this part, and the value contained in the putFile of the code was
`file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/20240304_064313_eewwqq1.jpg`.
However, when I click dfile:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/20240304_064313_eewwqq1.jpg in the log,
this error occurs:

> Cannot find file file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/20240304_064313_eewwqq1.jpg.

It works when I display the photo I took directly in Image View,
but why does the file not exist when I try to save it to Firebase with that uri?

After that, the downloadUrl value is Null, so you cannot proceed.

Comment: `I am in the process of receiving the URI of the photo I took, converting it to file format, then converting the converted file into URI` That seems a strange scenario. If you have an uri then why all the fuss to get another one?

Comment: It was said that it was correct to change the uri to the file format and then retrieve the uri of the file, rather than immediately applying the uri when the photo was taken, so I proceeded with that task.

Comment: Who said that? And whereever you did read that it makes no sense.

Comment: `Uri.fromFile(imageFile))` That does not convert to a content:// scheme but to an unusable file:// scheme.

Comment: So just use the uri you got from the media store with insert().

Comment: Perhaps this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).